# I'm making a program that adds the digits of a number together..for some reason, I can't call the function. Why? Using Python 2.x

Tags: python

```
def digit_sum(n):
    split = str(n).split()
    split_1 = str(split)
    print split_1[2]
    return sum(split_1[2], split_1[len(split_1) -  1]

digit_sum(21)
```

when I call digit sum with 21, I get:

```
File "digitsum.py", line 7
digit_sum(21)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is it not letting me call the function with the parameters of 21?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused a simple typographical error.* While your question may be technically on-topic here, these questions are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not running because you forgot to close the parenthesis on the last line of your function. This should fix the syntax error:

`return sum(split_1[2], split_1[len(split_1) -  1])`

However there is a problem in your logic. Running the function will raise: `TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]` because you have turned your integer argument into string with your first line in the function. What you are trying to do can easily be achieved using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map).

```
def digit_sum(n):
  return sum(map(int, str(n)))

print digit_sum(21) # 3
print digit_sum(178) # 16
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close parenthesis at the end of the last line of the function.

Comment: Also, `'23'.split()` == `['23']`. You probably want `map(int, list('23'))` which is `[2, 3]` ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to return like this

```
return sum(split_1[2], split_1[len(split_1) -  1])
```